# Передача данных по http из dll на сервер nodejs

Tags: javascript, fs

Такая проблема... Отправляю я данные из dll при помощи post запроса в размере около 7 мегабайт. А приходят данные в размере 15 килобайт. Большая часть обрезается...  Грубо говоря принимаю так:

```
http.createServer((req, res)=>{
   req.once("data", data=>{
      let myData = data.toString(); 
      // Вывожу эти данные в файл на сервере...
      fs.writeFile("path_to_file", (err)=>{
         if(err){ // ... }
         else { // ... }
      });
   });
}).listen(2000);
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, каким образом обычно принимаются данные? Потоки там или буферы нужны наверное? Или может что еще? Может проблема в другом вообще?

Answer (score 0):

Решение состоит в следующем. Данные приходят частями, а не все. Следовательно тут может быть несколько возможных способов приемки данных: приемка и обработка данных по мере их поступления или приемка всех данных целиком с последуюзей обработкой...

```
// Приемка и обработка данных по мере их поступления:
http.createServer((req, res)=>{
   req.on("data", data=>{
      let myData = data.toString(); 
      // Вывожу эти данные в файл на сервере добавляя их в конец...
      // Данный режим подойдет только в том случае, если сайт не проверяет эти файлы на предмет появления в файлах данных. Так как алгоритм программы скорее всего будет не корректно отработан, в силу не полных данных в файле... Поэтому это надо учитывать 
      fs.appendFile("path_to_file", myData, (err)=>{
         if(err){ // ... }
         else { res.end("Ok"); }
      });
   });
}).listen(2000);



// Приемка всех переданных данных с последующей обработкой:
http.createServer((req, res)=>{
   let datas = ""; // Сюда будем добавлять полученные данные.
   req.on("data", data=>{ // Если есть какие то данные, то конкатенируем их...
      datas += data.toString();
   });
   req.once("end", ()=>{ // Когда данные полностью прийдут, вызовится событие end, а в колбэке уже можно будет обрабатывать получение данных. Переменная datas будет содержать все данные...
      // Вывожу эти данные в файл на сервере...
      fs.writeFile("path_to_file", datas, (err)=>{
         if(err){ // ... }
         else { res.end("Ok"); }
      });
   });
 });
```